# Comparing array values in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a couple of (hopefully small) issues with this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gq0t4j93/22/

The functionality is working but my logic has gotten messed up along the way.

I'm nesting arrays of 'content' within a main array for the 'pageID'. The issue is that for HTML rendering, i need to first look at the page_type_id of the first 'page' element and then look at the panel_type_id of the content element.

My first problem is that my forloop at line 107 seems to only access odd number pageIDs but if I remove it it will access all of them.

But the other real issue is that At line 109, I want to change

```
if (currentJSONobject.content.length >= 1) {
  leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
}
if (currentJSONobject.content.length >= 2) {
  rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
} else {
  rightContent.innerHTML = '';
}
```

To instead use page_type_id and panel_type_id instead of length, so:

```
if (currentJSONobject.page_type_id == 2) {
  fullColumn.style.display = "none";
  if (currentJSONobject.content.panel_type_id == 2) {
    leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
  }
  if (currentJSONobject.content.panel_type_id == 3) {
    rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
  }
}
```

It seems simple but I can't figure out how to actually change it that way.

Again, it's cycling correctly and showing the content but I need to be able to evolve the logic for several page and panel types, hopefully someone can see where I'm going wrong here

UPDATE:

Switching from ternary in accepted answer to if/else

```
for(var i = 0; i < currentJSONobject.content.length; i++){

    fullContent.innerHTML = '';
    rightContent.innerHTML = '';
    leftContent.innerHTML = '';
    topLeftContent = '';
    topRightContent = '';
    bottomLeftContent = '';
    bottomRightContent = '';

    if(currentJSONobject.content[i].page_type_id == 1){

        leftColumn.style.display = "none";
        rightColumn.style.display = "none";
        leftColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
        rightColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
        rightColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
        leftColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";

        if(currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 1){
            fullContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
        }

    }else if(currentJSONobject.content[i].page_type_id == 2){

        fullColumn.style.display = "none";
        leftColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
        rightColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
        rightColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
        leftColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";

        if(currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 2){
            leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
        } if(currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 3){
            rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].content;
        }
    }


//   fullContent.innerHTML = '';
//   rightContent.innerHTML = '';
//   leftContent.innerHTML = '';

// fullContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 1 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : fullContent.innerHTML;

// leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 2 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : leftContent.innerHTML;

// rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 3 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : rightContent.innerHTML;

}
```

Comment: `original_json` has two objects with the same **pageID**. `"pageID": "93"`.

Comment: Right, so the way I restructured it, I would have an array for that pageID of 93 containing two content elements assigned to that page.

Comment: So I'm trying to say "If the top level array for pages has pageID, get all c ontent elements with that pageID, but I only need the page_type_id of the top page element, and the panel_type_id of each nested/content element, if that makes sense

Comment: The fiddle isn't showing any output. Can you please check? May be CSS is missing.

Comment: @KetanYekale sorry, try now. Showing fine for me as well

Comment: Page 93 in your pages_array has two items in its content. currentJsonObject is that item, it then loops through the content (which is two items) and increments counter by two. It then grabs the THIRD item in your pages_array, which is page 95, because that for loop increased counter by 2. Also, page 96 has 'page 95' in its content, so that is fine, it is just saying the wrong page. That for loop is really doing nothing because your 'ifs' print the multiple contents anyway... should just get rid of it.

Comment: @TylerDahle so I could get rid of it, and just say page type 4 has 3 different content elements I would just map them by [0] [1] or [2]?

Comment: @TylerDahle And then how can I make my 'ifs' use page_type_id or panel_type_id instead of just the length? I'm trying to take the guess work out of the logic

Comment: It would be better to get rid of the ifs and dynamically add items based on how many there are in content (using that for loop). BUT, you need to get rid of count in the for loop. Count should be at the end of the setTimeout, not in the for loop because the for loop is looping through a different array than count is accessing.

Comment: I was just using the IFs because I have 4 page types, and 7 panel types, only some of which belong to certain page types. But if you can suggest a different way to structure it I"m open. This is just an example that I'm trying to expand once I have it figured out.

Comment: I removed the for loop and I see what you're saying there. I'll play with the count now too. But will I be able to make my if logic change so that it says 'if page_type_id == or if panel_type_id ==?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gq0t4j93/39/ this fiddle shows my changes toward the concept I'm describing but it's no longer printing the content. I'm simply trying to change out content based on each page change but at each change assign certain content to certain divs, with the option to hide the other divs

Comment: Your initial if is using `currentJSONobject.content.panel_type_id`, but content is an array, you have to access the element in the array. Simply adding [0] after content made your code start outputting as expected. And without the for loop, it only prints one page 93 when the array has two.

Comment: @TylerDahle Can you share an example of doing this dynamically without the IFs? As long as I can set the page and panel type to show what content needs to display and which divs to hide

Comment: part of the reason I was using that for loop was so that no matter how many elements I had, it would only look at the current one using [i]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. You actually will want if's (which the ternary does) if you have a select amount of page types that you want to handle differently when encountered. I am unsure of how you want to display the information, like if you want to display the duplicate 93s (the for loop goes through each, but just doing the equals operator overwrites it so it only shows one at a time). Or if you want to show any right, left, or full content at the same time. If you want to show right, left, and full at the same time, you would want to replace the '' on the 'else' part of the ternary with full/left/rightContent.innerHTML to preserve their values. Or replace with normal If statements.

```js
const original_json = [{
    "pageID": "93",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "86",
    "panel_type_id": "2",
    "cont_id": "138",
    "contID": "138",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nLeft 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "93",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "3",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nRight 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "94",
    "page_type_id": "1",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "1",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nFull Page<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "95",
    "page_type_id": "1",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "1",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nFull Page 2<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
    {
    "pageID": "96",
    "page_type_id": "1",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "1",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nFull Page 3<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
];

let counter = 0;

var fullContent = document.getElementById('fullContent');
var leftContent = document.getElementById('leftContent');
var rightContent = document.getElementById('rightContent');

var fullColumn = document.getElementById('fullColumn');
var leftColumn = document.getElementById('leftColumn');
var rightColumn = document.getElementById('rightColumn');


// loop through original json
// for each item, get page ID and see if we've already created a new Page object for it
// if we have, add the object from the original json to the "content" array of the new page object
// otherwise, create a new Page object to put in our new array
const pages_array = original_json.reduce(function(pages_array, item, index, original_json) {
  const current_pageID = item.pageID;
  const exisiting_page = pages_array.find(page => page.pageID === current_pageID);

  if (exisiting_page === undefined) {
    const new_Page = {
      pageID: current_pageID,
      content: [item]
    }
    pages_array.push(new_Page);
  } else {
    exisiting_page.content.push(item)
  }

  return pages_array;
}, []);

// Open console to see data
console.clear();
//console.log(pages_array); //this prints correct array

setInterval(() => { //here I loop through pages, but i need to loop within here over content to render html
  fullContent.innerHTML = '';
  rightContent.innerHTML = '';
  leftContent.innerHTML = '';
  const currentJSONobject = pages_array[counter];
  for(var i = 0; i < currentJSONobject.content.length; i++){
   fullContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 1 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : fullContent.innerHTML;
    
    leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 2 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : leftContent.innerHTML;
    
    rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 3 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : rightContent.innerHTML;
  }

  //console.log(pages_array[counter])

  counter += 1;
  if (counter === pages_array.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }

}, 1500)
```

```html
<div class="row middle" id="middle" style="background-image: url();">
  
  <div class="col-lg-6 fullColumn">

    <div class="fullContent" id="fullContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Half Page Divs -->
  <div class="col-lg-6 leftColumn">

    <div class="leftContent" id="leftContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 rightColumn">

    <div class="rightContent" id="rightContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- End Half Page Divs -->

</div>
<!-- End Row Middle -->
```

Comment: Shouldn't that use [i] instead of [0] though? That example should be showing left 93 and right 93 simultaneously but only shows Left 93 now

Comment: Basically, if there are multiple elements per pageID, I will want them all shown but I'm just using the logic to decide their DIV, that's all

Comment: So when page 93 is active it should show Left 93 and Right 93, when page 94 is active it should only show Full Page, page 95 should only show Full Page 2 and 96 should only show Full Page 3

Comment: Is it now more like what you are after? To only display one set of content at a time, I just cleared out the contents at each interval.

Comment: Almost, but I still can't figure out the page 93 element. It shows left 93 twice instead of left and right. So it needs to iterate the content

Comment: I think it's because we still have content[0] but it would almost need another iterator or something of that nature wouldn't it?

Comment: Thank you so much, I think that's it! I believe this way I should be able to expand it for multiple page and panel types

Comment: Will this allow me to do a display none on the other divs?

Comment: You could. I would probably switch to actual if/else instead of ternary if you want to do 'if this page type, set html, else, hide the div' kind of thing.

Comment: cool I may do that, but what you did here puts me back on that path correctly. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, last question: Am I able to access the page element in the for loop here? IN other words, can I set an IF based on the page_type_id of that highest page array?

Comment: Yes, you'd just do currentJSONObject.content[i].page_type_id if I am understanding the question correctly... Your currentJSONObject is the thing with pageId and content, where content has all your page data (panel type, page type, etc...).